# Ajax doesn't work because lack of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX script implemented on my site, that is controlling some inputs, but there is one case where my input is only shown after a range slider is used. If I don't use my range slider only other inputs, my script won't run. My AJAX is the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e){
         // Something went wrong
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // div section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
 }
 // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.

 var bedno   = document.getElementById('bedno').value;
 var district   = document.getElementById('district').value;
 var loc        = document.getElementById('location').value;
 var price1   = document.getElementById('price1').value;
 var price2   = document.getElementById('price2').value;

 var queryString = "?bedno=" + bedno ;
 queryString +=  "&district=" + district + "&price1=" + price1 + "&price2=" + price2 + "&location=" + loc;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + 
                              queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
```

var price1 and price2 are the two variables that are not defined when the range slider is left unused. I think this is the reason why my script won't run. What could cause the problem?

My slider is generated only when the slider is used, so the value is missing till the visitor clicks on the slider, but I want it to be shown without the us e of the slider script. :

```
$('.priceSlider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 2000,
    values: [500, 1500],
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('.priceSlider .sliderTooltip .stLabel').html(
            '€' + ui.values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$2,") + 
            ' <span class="fa fa-arrows-h"></span> ' +
            '€' + ui.values[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") +
            ' <input type="hidden" id="price1" style="position: absolute;" onchange="ajaxFunction()"  value="'+  ui.values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "2") +'" />' +
            ' <input type="hidden" id="price2" style="position: absolute;" onchange="ajaxFunction()" value="'+  ui.values[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "1") +'" />'

        );
        var priceSliderRangeLeft = parseInt($('.priceSlider .ui-slider-range').css('left'));
        var priceSliderRangeWidth = $('.priceSlider .ui-slider-range').width();
        var priceSliderLeft = priceSliderRangeLeft + ( priceSliderRangeWidth / 2 ) - ( $('.priceSlider .sliderTooltip').width() / 2 );
        $('.priceSlider .sliderTooltip').css('left', priceSliderLeft);
    }
});
```

Any possible solutions are merely appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I missed that: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: bedno, district, ... make sure you have all these elements.  The error message says one of them is missing.  And make sure they are input elements, so they have a 'value' property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do this, with price1 and price2

```
if(document.getElementById('price2')) {
  var price2   = document.getElementById('price2').value;
}
else {
  var price2 = 0;
}
```

But since I see you use jQuery, you should use the jQuery way of doing Ajax.